# program to list all primes between 2 numbers and how many where found

Tags: java

```
package com.mycompany.test;

/**
 *
 * @author Lenovo
 */


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int start = 5;
        int end = 98;

        for (int i=start;i<=end;i++)
        {
            int flag=0;
            for (int j=start;j<i;j++)
            {
                if(i % j==0)
                {
                    flag=1;
                }
            }
            if(flag==0)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Every time I run the program the first few numbers printed are mixed with nonprime numbers. also, I cant figure out how to add a counter to how many prime numbers were found.

Comment: I suggest you run the code in a debugger. A debugger allows you to trace the code flow while monitoring variables. It might also help to see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .   By the way, a better design would use a method `public static boolean isPrime (int n)`, which would return `true` if `n` (the parameter) is prime, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: You are checking `i % j`, but then you start your `j` from 5 so numbers like 4 will pass

Comment: @Old Dog Programmer I have to stay with void string main args as per the rules on the program. I have to use basic stuff like this. I also don't know if I can use a debugger

Comment: Your loops should be more like `for (int i=start;i<=end;i++)` and `for (int j=2;j<i;j++)`

Comment: Netbeans has a debugger. But, you might try an old fashioned method of debugging: Use pen and paper for the memory, and pretend you are the computer. For every variable in your code (`start`, `end`, `i`, `j`, `flag`) make a column.  Step through the code. Each time the value of a variable changes, write the new value in the column.  If you need to, use other areas of the paper.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer I changed j=start to j=2 and that fixed the nonprime printing problem. how would you suggest I add a count to how many primes it found?

Comment: @qrsngky   XD I figured that out then came back to the site to see you recommending that. lol

Comment: You may want to research how to use continue with a label to streamline your code.

Comment: You know how to use an `if` statement. You know you can use `{` `}` to create code blocks. You can have more than one statement in a code block:  `if (foo < bar) { foo *= 4; bar -= 3; System.out.println ("Hello"); }`

Comment: You can make a variable, say, `int found = 0;` after `int end = 98;` (outside the loops) and use `found++;` instead of just printing `i` out.